# Swift - Pass data from Base ViewController to two Container ViewControllers after loading from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Base View Controller with two Container ViewControllers]

I know this may be a simple solution but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to load data from Firestore in my Base ViewController to then populate two Container Viewcontrollers at the same time.(I want to do it this way to save on Read Cost) I've been trying to go the segue route but the segue is called before my data is finished loading from Firestore. I need the data to be present to popular the two different Container Viewcontrollers(One container is a chart. The other container is a line graph). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    var db: Firestore!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()

        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork(){
            print("Internet Connection Available!")

            loadFirestoreData()

        } else {
            print("Internet Connection not Available!")
        }
    }

// Load Firestore Data

    func loadFirestoreData() {

        db.collection("chartGraph").document("companyX")
            .getDocument{ (document, err) in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                } else {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChartSegue", sender: document!.data()!)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "LineGraphSegue", sender: document!.data()!)
                }
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if identifier == "ChartSegue" {
            let vc1 = segue.destinationViewController as? ChartViewController
            vc1.dataLoaded(data: (sender as? [String: Any])!)
        }

        if identifier == "LineGraphSegue" {
            let vc2 = segue.destinationViewController as? LineGraphViewController
            vc2.dataLoaded(data: (sender as? [String: Any])!)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The segue is called before data is loaded from Firebase because it's not been coded correctly to account for Firebase being asynchronous. A segue is a simple and common method to 'pass' the data. You can additionally just add a variable in each sub-view controller to hold the data - after you instantiate each subview's controller, populate that var with the data and then present the controller. We could probably help with the Firebase issue if code was included. Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the code update in the question. That actually looks fine now as the segue is being called within the firebase closure, which means the firebase data will be valid. We don't know what happens here `.dataLoaded` but everything before that is solid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to Container in your `MainViewController`.

For that you should add instance variables to `MainViewController` that will hold a reference to the container controllers, not just the view. You'll need to set it in `prepareForSegue`.

So the beginning of `MainViewController` look something like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {



    var containerViewChartController: ChartViewController?
    var containerViewLineGraphController: LineGraphViewController?

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let controller = segue.destination as? ChartViewController {
            containerViewChartController = controller

        } else if let controller = segue.destination as? LineGraphViewController {
           containerViewLineGraphController = controller
      }
    }
```

then you can call container methods like this

```
func button_Container() {
        containerViewChartController?.changeData(yourData)
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a bad answer but, the OP said a segue didn't work which means there's a larger issue. The problem is the OP isn't accounting for the asynchronous nature of Firebase and this solution will also have the same issue because the segue will display before the data is loaded.

Comment: Yes ... but he sets the variable pointing to `destination controllers` in `prepareForSegue` ... i am not passing any data in `prepareForSegue` just setting controllers ... then once he has data through async call ... he can perform any action using those instance variables we set in `prepareForSegue`

Comment: OP segue is not working because asynchronous operation ... he does not have data when segue calls ... but what i have done is to get references to those container controller to perform actions on them once i have data which i will get through async task...

Comment: let me know if there is any Ambiguity.. or how i can improve my answer ? but i believe it will work ...

Comment: @user3111472 does it helps you ?

Comment: @jawadAli - This actually worked for what I needed, but I know it may be a better way using segue somehow in an Async way. I didn't have to use ContainerToMaster because I'm not sending data back to the Master.

Comment: Yeah - now the question has been updated with the Firebase code it looks good.